# how to use object as vaue for multiprocesing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am attempting to pass a list as a global variable however I couldn't find a ctypes from the ctypes library that would work.  Instead I have put a wrapper around a test list to see what happens.  When I do this I don't get the expected behavior that I want.  Here is a sample of my code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Manager
import ctypes
def dostuff(x):
    with lock:
        counter.value = counter.value + 1
        init.value.inX.append(counter.value)
        print("th:", x, "counter:", counter.value, "init:", init.value.inX)
    
def my_initializer(c, l, i):
    global counter, lock, init
    counter = c
    lock = l
    init = i
class my_init:
    inX = []
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
init = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.py_object,my_init)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=my_initializer, initargs=[counter,lock, init])
inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
pool.map(dostuff, inputs)
```

And here is my output:

```
th: 1 counter: 1 init: [1]
th: 3 counter: 2 init: [2]
th: 4 counter: 3 init: [2, 3]
th: 2 counter: 4 init: [4]
```

Here is the expected output:

```
th: 1 counter: 1 init: [1]
th: 3 counter: 2 init: [1, 2]
th: 4 counter: 3 init: [1, 2, 3]
th: 2 counter: 4 init: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you are trying to achieve here? If you need a list, why not use `Manager().list()`?

PS you do not need locks when using `Manager` resources - Manager takes care of that for you.

Comment: thanks.  that worked!  greatly appreciated!